# Join completely two different SELECT queries

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have two tables 'abcd' and 'abcd1'. Like below:

abcd:

```
+----+------+--------+------+------+
| id | name | phno   | add1 | add2 |
+----+------+--------+------+------+
| 1  | a    | 123    | mno  | pqr  |
| 2  | a    | 1234   | mno1 | pqr1 |
| 3  | a    | 1234   | NULL | NULL |
| 4  | a    | 12345  | NULL | NULL |
| 5  | a    | 123456 | NULL | NULL |
+----+------+--------+------+------+
```

abcd1:

```
+----+------+--------+------+------+
| id | name | phno   | add1 | add2 |
+----+------+--------+------+------+
| 1  | a    | 123    | mno  | pqr  |
| 2  | a    | 1234   | mno1 | pqr1 |
| 3  | a    | 1234   | mno2 | pqr2 |
| 4  | a    | 12345  | mno3 | pqr3 |
| 5  | a    | 123456 | NULL | NULL |
+----+------+--------+------+------+
```

Now, I have applied the first query on first table i.e. abcd:

```
select id,name,phno 
from abcd 
where id='3';
```

And this gives me the below result:

```
+----+------+--------+
| id | name | phno   |
+----+------+--------+
| 3  | a    | 1234   |
+----+------+--------+
```

Secondly, I have applied the next query for 'abcd1' table, i.e:

```
select add1,add2 
from abcd1 
where name='a' 
      and add1!='NULL' 
      and add2!='NULL' 
order by id desc limit 1;
```

And this gives me the below result:

```
+------+------+
| add1 | add2 |
+------+------+
| mno3 | pqr3 |
+------+------+
```

These two queries works completely fine for me.

I want a single sql query through which I can retrieve a row looks like below:

```
+----+------+--------+------+------+
| id | name | phno   | add1 | add2 |
+----+------+--------+------+------+
| 3  | a    | 1234   | mno3 | pqr3 |
+----+------+--------+------+------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure it makes much sense to do so, since the latter query's results have almost nothing to do with the results of former, but you could just CROSS JOIN:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM (query1) AS t1
CROSS JOIN (query2) AS t2
;
```

Comment: its very simple and really helpful solution. thank u very much.

Comment: As noted in another answer here, take care when using it with subqueries with multiple results as you'll get the "Cartesian product" of those results.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are joining the two tables on `name`:

```
select t1.id, t1.name, t1.phno 
from abcd AS t1
join abcd1 AS t2 ON t2.name = t1.name 
where t1.id = '3'
      AND t2.add1 IS NOT NULL 
      AND t2.add2 IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY t2.id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Even though they happen to match, nothing in the question suggests the `name` SELECTed in the first query is being used as the condition for the second one's WHERE.

Answer (score 0):

If you are **absolutely certain** both your queries always return one single row, you could use an `CROSS JOIN` to "combine" both rows into one.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  select id,name,phno 
  from abcd 
  where id='3'
) AS t1
CROSS JOIN
(
  select add1,add2 
  from abcd1 
  where name='a' 
    and add1!='NULL' 
    and add2!='NULL' 
  order by id desc limit 1
) AS t2
```

You can [try it here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mrKXbEfqYccys2mG5jRwA3/1)

But be aware that if your queries respectively return N and M rows, you'll end up with N*M rows using the query above.

**EDIT:** @Uueerdo beat me to it, if this solves your problem, please consider accepting his answer ;) (i'm leaving this one up in case people want to use the fiddle)